# Cleanest way to decorate Django's dispatch method

Tags: django, python-decorators

I stumbled upon a code that is used to provide some args to the request method. Problem is that I'm not that sure if it is the **cleanest way** to handle this case.

```
def check_permissions(check_mixins):
"""
:param check_mixins: is given to the inner decorator
Decorator that will automatically populate some parameters when
using dispatch() toward the right method (get(), post())

"""
  def _decorator(_dispatch):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
```

Is it a problem if "self" isn't passed in the method definition in here...

```
        for mixin in check_mixins:
            kwargs = mixin.check(request, *args, **kwargs)
            if isinstance(kwargs, HttpResponseRedirect):
                return kwargs

        return _dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper

  return _decorator


class UserLoginMixin(object):

def check(request, *args, **kwargs):
```

... and here ? It seems so ugly in my IDE

```
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated() and not user.is_anonymous():
        kwargs['user'] = user
        return kwargs
    return redirect('user_login')

class AppoExistMixin(object):

def check(request, *args, **kwargs):
```

Here too...

```
    appo_id = kwargs['appo_id']
    try:
        appoff = IdAppoff.objects.get(id=appo_id)
        kwargs['appoff'] = appoff
        del kwargs['appo_id']
        return kwargs
    except IdAppoff.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR,
                         "Item doesn't exist!")
    return redirect('home')



class SecurityMixin(View):
"""
    Mixin that dispatch() to the right method with augmented kwargs.
    kwargs are added if they match to specific treatment.
"""

data = []

def __init__(self, authenticators):
    super(SecurityMixin, self).__init__()
    # Clearing data in order to not add useless param to kwargs
    self.data.clear()
    # Build the list that contain each authenticator providing
    # context increase
    for auth in authenticators:
        self.data.append(auth)

@method_decorator(check_permissions(data))
```

Why data and not self.data ? How is it possible ?

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(SecurityMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Each view then inherits from *SecurityMixin* and got `authenticators = [UserLoginMixin, ...]` as class attribute.

The problem I have **sometimes** (I can't reproduce the bug...) is that I got KeyError on augmented kwargs while URL definition is properly set. eg:

```
appo_id = kwargs['appo_id']
KeyError: 'appo_id'Exception
```

I've been looking for hours and it seems that I will never have the solution... It's a bit frustrating.

If someone could help It'll be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a hunch that improper handling of class attributes is at fault.

---

**CLASS VS INSTANCE**

The *class* attribute `data` is overwritten every time `SecurityMixin.__init__` is called:

```
class A:
    data = []

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.data.clear() # self.data references the class attribute
        for x in args:
            self.data.append(x)

    x = A('foo')
    # A.data = ['foo']
    # x.data = ['foo']
    y = A('bar')
    # A.data = ['bar']
    # y.data = ['bar']
    # x.data = ['bar'] !!
```

HOWEVER:

```
class A:
    data = ['I am empty']

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.data = [] # redeclaring data as an instance attribute
        for x in args:
            self.data.append(x)

    x = A('foo')
    # A.data = ['I am empty']
    # x.data = ['foo']
    y = A('bar')
    # A.data = ['I am empty']
    # y.data = ['bar']
    # x.data = ['foo']
```

This *class* attribute `data` is passed to the decorator (you cannot pass an instance attribute to a method decorator, i.e. self.data, because the instance does not yet exist during decorator declaration).
The wrapped function, however, does have access to the instance if it is passed in ('self' argument).

Django's `method_decorator` removes this self argument; that decorator is used to transform a *function* decorator (which does not get a `self` argument implicitly) into a *method* decorator (which gets a `self` parameter implicitly). That's why you do not have to include `self` in the list of parameters for the various mixin check methods as it was removed by `method_decorator`. To put it simply: use `method_decorator` to decorate a method with a function decorator. Read up on it here [decorating CBVs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class).

Knowing that, I am not really sure why `check_permissions` should be a *function* decorator as it is now when you only use it to decorate methods.
You could just decorate dispatch with `check_permissions` itself:

```
def check_permissions(_dispatch):
    def _decorator(self, request, *args, **kwargs): # adding self
        for mixin in self.data: # referencing the INSTANCE data
            kwargs = mixin.check(request, *args, **kwargs) 
            if isinstance(kwargs, HttpResponseRedirect):
                return kwargs
        return _dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs) # don't forget self here
    return _decorator


@check_permissions
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

Maybe some view is trying to check `AppoExistMixin` because it is in that view's data list, although it should not be - and the view's kwargs do not include 'appo_id'. You could also try being explicit by passing the wanted check mixins directly to the decorator: `@method_decorator(check_permissions([UserLoginMixin, ...]))`. This way you you don't have to mess with class vs instance attributes.

Also... you should rename `data` to something that you are unlikely to overwrite with your own variable.

If you want to be super-lazy you could just do:

```
appo_id = kwargs.get('appo_id',False)
if not appo_id: return kwargs
```

But this would only fix that particular error in that one view. It's ignoring a symptom instead of curing the disease.

---

Some more explanation:

function vs method. `check_permissions` is a *function*, while `dispatch()` is a *method*. You cannot simply use a function decorator on a method: for one, because the implicit argument `self` (the instance the *method* belongs to) is passed to the decorator as well, although it may not expect it.
That is where django's `method_decorator` comes in by removing  and storing `self` within the decorator. Compare the two signatures: `wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs)` vs `_decorator(self, request, *args, **kwargs)`. In the former, `method_decorator` 'absorbed' `self` before the function decorator is called.
Think of it as an adapter, a decorator for the decorator, that 'bridges the gap' between function and method. Use it if you don't want to/cannot alter the decorator.
In your case, however, you **can** change the decorator to make it work with a method - thus you don't need django's `method_decorator`.

Comment: Thx a lot Coffee for your answer ! I might be able to resolve the problem !

Comment: Let me know what happens. Messing with class instances and mutable method parameters [click](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/) are things that can really obscure what the real problem is.

Comment: I modified the code about 2 weeks ago with data class attribute converted to an instance attribute. And I modified the decorator definition with your code. It works really well. No more KeySurpriseError :)

Comment: But I'm not sure that I have really understood the true differences between the former decorator and the new one you brought

Comment: @Rick Star: Updated my post.

Comment: OK ! You said that Django's "method_decorator" is used to decorates methods and stores self itself. The former check_permissions didn't embed self in wrapper() while the new one does. Isn't it the method_decorator's job to deal with "self" ? Why is there a problem ? (thx a lot by the way :)

Comment: `self` is needed so the wrapped function (here: `wrapper() or _decorator()`) can access the _instance's_ `data` attribute (`for mixin in self.data:`). This whole thingamabob is done so the mixins are _per instance_, instead of per class - as the latter, I assume, caused the unexpected behaviour. That is why using `method_decorator` would be a bad idea. I hope this explains it, if not keep asking.